D2RQ JDBC driver for MYSQL MariaDB is deprecated
by using

d2rq 0.8.1
xampp 3.3.0 with 10.4.32-MariaDB
jdbc driver file mysql-connector-j-9.0.0.jar version: Connector/J 9.0.0
Java SDK: openjdk version "18" 2022-03-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18+36-2087)

I was able to test connect & query MySQL DB in java code successfully.
everything is Ok till now.
Now, I want to use d2rq, so I copied driver file mysql-connector-j-9.0.0.jar to folder:
D2RQ\d2rq-0.8.1\lib\db-drivers 

then I tried to get mapping using d2rq command:
generate-mapping -o iswc.ttl jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iswc?user=root&password=&useSSL=false

it gaves this error
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Database connection to jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iswc?user=root failed (user: null): No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iswc?user=root (E54)
'password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'useSSL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

any suggestion to solve this error.

If you're connecting to MariaDB, you should be using the MariaDB Connector/J, and if you insist on using MySQL Connector/J, your JDBC URL should start with jdbc:mysql:, not with jdbc:mariadb: as MySQL Connector/J doesn't recognize the jdbc:mariadb: protocol.

Also, the problem has nothing to do with that deprecation warning, the problem is: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iswc?user=root" (because MySQL Connector/J doesn't support jdbc:mariadb:)

I already query data successfully using mysql connector with simple test in java code, but I also tried to use mariadb connector mariadb-java-client-3.4.0.jar with d2rq, and got the following confusing error about Mysql: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl
at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.sql.ConnectedDB.lowerCaseTableNames(ConnectedDB.java:378)
at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.dbschema.DatabaseSchemaInspector.toRelationName(DatabaseSchemaInspector.java:272)
at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.dbschema.DatabaseSchemaI
@MarkRotteveel

according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) work unchanged with MariaDB.

Well, your choice is to either use MySQL Connector/J and a JDBC URL that starts with jdbc:mysql: instead of jdbc:mariadb:, or use MariaDB Connector/J and ensure the right driver class is loaded (hint: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is not the right name for the MariaDB Connector/J).
